# Mount an external drive in a linux server through SSH

Tags: ssh, remote-server, ubuntu-server

I have an Ubuntu Server. I have an external drive connected through USB. I use external drive with jellyfin for my movies. It works fine, but when I reboot server. The drive is no longer mounted, and I have to connect my monitor to the server and mount it. Is there a way to mount it remotely through SSH? I already tried to auto mount it in a script, which I don't remember, but that seems to not work (it did for a while).

Comment: I figured out that all to open a file called fstab in the /etc/folder and add a line for my drive. I did already have it there, but it was commented out. I uncommented it it, but it gave me an error that the mounting point did not exist. not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.